# Copiar uma string para a outra em C++

Tags: c++, string

Estou fazendo uma atividade escolar onde eu tenho uma lista de títulos de livros. Cada título armazenado num campo string de uma estrutura.
Preciso ordenar essa lista em ordem alfabetica atraves do quicksort onde tambem devo implementar o algoritmo.
Meu problema consiste exatamente na troca dos valores. Uso a função strcmp para comparar as strings. Estou fazendo dessa forma mas não esta funcionado:

```
             int Ordenacao::particionaString (string vet[], int ini, int fim)
{
    int esquerda = ini+1;
    int direita = fim;
    string pivo = vet[ini];
    string aux;
    int n = 0;

        while(esquerda < direita){
            n = strcmp(vet[esquerda].c_str(), pivo.c_str());                        // < 0 a primeira e menor
            while(n < 0){
                esquerda++;
                n = strcmp(vet[esquerda].c_str(), pivo.c_str());
            }
            n = strcmp(vet[direita].c_str(), pivo.c_str());
            while(n >0){
                direita--;
                n = strcmp(vet[direita].c_str(), pivo.c_str());
            }
            if(esquerda < direita){
                cout << "Trocando " << vet[esquerda] << " com " << vet[direita] << endl;
                aux = vet[esquerda];
                vet[esquerda] = vet[direita];
                vet[direita] = aux;
            }
        }

    vet[ini] = vet[direita];
    vet[direita] = pivo;
    return direita;

}
```

Não consigo usar a função strcpy da biblioteca string pois ele pede um char* no destino e estou trabalhando com string.
As atribuições com o = estão dando erro.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: E pra que fazer essa confusão toda? Se está programando em C++. faça um código C++, não use C, Além de tudo é ineficiente.

Comment: O que voce me sugere? Entendo muito pouco, estou aprendendo ainda

Comment: Sugiro aprender fazer em C++, não faça em C quando quer aprender outra linguagem só porque o compilador aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em c++ `std::string` já segue a ordem lexicográfica. Ou seja, basta comparar com os operadores relacionais como `<`, `>`, etc. O único cuidado que deve ter é que ele diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Já a função `strcmp` que você está usando é para comparar arrays de caracteres no C. Não há nenhum motivo para você usar essa função e nem para chamar `c_str()`.

Outro ponto é o uso de `string vet[]`. Aqui você está passando como um array do C de objetos `std::string`, que na verdade vai degenerar para um ponteiro e portanto dentro da função `particionaString` você não vai saber o tamanho desse array e precisa passar essa informação (como você já faz). Não use arrays puros do C. Use `std::vector`, `std::array` ou outro container da biblioteca do C++ que assim você evita toda essa complicação de array degenerando para ponteiro e os containers do C++ sabem seu próprio tamanho.

Na hora de fazer a troca dos valores, você também pode usar a função [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), ao invés de manualmente criar a variável auxiliar e fazer a troca você mesmo.